# Linux GeoIP CLI app

Tags: linux, command-line, geoip

I'm looking for a Linux CLI app that can accept a list of IP addresses and draw dots on the world map. All I want is to get an image file containing the world map and dots pointing to IP locations.

A webservice won't do it, because I might need to run this on computers that don't have permanent access to the Internet, so I need a standalone app. AFAIK there are freely downloadable GeoIP databases, so this shouldn't be a problem.

I'm posting here because I failed to find such an app by googling and I need advice from the community before eventually trying to write something like this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you can not use an online service, you have to bring the whole database (containing the mapping of ip-range to location) onto the machine(s). as far as i can see,

- http://www.ip2location.com

seems to offer such a database (you have to pay for it). it further offers APIs in several languages, for example C:

- http://www.ip2location.com/c.aspx

another (free) option seems to be

- http://ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php

with that you can easily hack your own cli-tool, which then paints some dots onto another picture (a world map).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the [MaxMind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) free database, you may want to use [geoip](https://github.com/cinsk/geoip).

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.